# Minimatch pattern for two paths where one is prefix of the other

Tags: cypress, glob, minimatch

I am writing an integration test with cypress and having trouble with minimatch pattern.

I have two endpoints that I need to stub.
`/users/1` and `/users/1/profile`.

The way I am trying to mock these two endpoints with `cy.intercept()` is the following.
For the first url, `/users/1`, I tried `cy.intercept('GET', '/users/1', {})`.

For the secton url , `/users/1/profile`, I tried `cy.intercept('GET', '/users/1/profile', {})`.

The problem is that the first pattern intercepts twice.

Can I get some help on this?? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I, too, fell into this problem when first using `cy.intercept`. The solution is to pass in a `RouteMatcher` object to the method. In particular, you'll want to use the last method signature from the image below:

[image: usage]

In the `RouteMatcher` object, you can specify a `path` property. Here's the description of the `path` property:

[image: path property]

In essence, using the `path` property of the `RouteMatcher` object does an exact match against the given string, whereas the `url` parameter in the 1st and 2nd method signatures does a substring match against the given string.

So what you'll want is:

```
cy.intercept(
    {method: 'GET', path: '/users/1'},
    {body: {}}
)

cy.intercept(
    {method: 'GET', path: '/users/1/profile'},
    {body: {}}
)
```

In my opinion, this slight change from Cypress between the `cy.route` and `cy.intercept` methods was weird and a bit unexpected on the first run-through.