# Cypress intercept not honoring actual pathname/query

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I've had this a few times now, 100+ routes in this cypress application however sometimes they work, sometimes they don't, the issue is that even though i've setup my routes correctly they're showing up as an asterix in the route section (see screenshots), after the `/campaign` route you can see a bunch of asterix, which are all the interceptions using pathname and query.

Why are these showing up as a wild matching route?

I've tried regular expression matches, pathname & query, default method & url:

```
cy.intercept('GET', new RegExp(`\/placement\?where\={"campaign"\:"${campaign.id}"}$`), {
    body: placements
});
cy.intercept('GET', `/placement?where={"campaign":"${campaign.id}"}`, {
    body: placements
});
cy.intercept({
    method: 'GET',
    pathname: `/placement`
    query: {
        where: `{"campaign":"${campaign.id}"}`
    }
}, {
    body: placements
});
```

As per their documentation, i don't see why ANY of the above 3 examples shouldn't work, they all match the same thing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code in images.

Comment: I've updated and put some code examples in there, left the screenshot for reference

Comment: The `path` property does an exact match to the path, whereas `url` does a substring match. See [my other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056942/minimatch-pattern-for-two-paths-where-one-is-prefix-of-the-other/66057775#comment116817990_66057775) for more detail.

Comment: Yep i know @natn2323 however i think there's something else here, because changing this to: `cy.intercept('GET', `/placement?where=*${campaign.id}*`, { body: placements });` works, i think the curly's in the url are screwing with the minimatch